# Handling multiple self-consistent solutions with DFT+U

Tags: density-functional-theory, magnetism, self-consistent-field, dft-u

It is well-established that within the DFT+*U* framework, one can achieve several self-consistent solutions with greatly varying energies for the same exact magnetic ordering. In 2010, [Meredig et al.](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.195128) showed that a relatively simple "*U*-ramping" method could be employed to more easily identify the true ground state solution for troublesome DFT+*U* cases.

Since it has been over a decade since the aforementioned paper, is this still considered to be the optimal approach when carrying out DFT+*U* calculations? Are there any other methods commonly used to identify the ground state solution when carrying out DFT+*U* calculations?

Comment: As it's been close to a year since this question was asked, I wonder if you learned anything about this problem over the last 11 months that you could share with us in an update?

Comment: My experience is with Hartree-Fock and post-HF methods like coupled-cluster and CI, much more than with DFT, but the [method that I use](http://slater.chemie.uni-mainz.de/xaces2/aces2man/node35.html) to find lower and lower self-consistent HF solutions is to form the orbital Hessian and diagonalize it to find any negative eigenvalues, then use something like [`HFSTABILITY=FOLLOW`](http://slater.chemie.uni-mainz.de/cfour/index.php?n=Main.Hartree-FockStabilityAnalysis) in CFOUR or Aces2 to "follow" the eigenvectors to the lowest eigenvalue of the orbital Hessian.

Comment: Table 1 of [my 2021 paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fchem.2021.749779/full) shows that doing this makes a big difference not only in the HF energy but also for the post-HF. Gaussian is able to do this type of calculation to find lower and lower self-consistent solutions in **DFT**, using the keyword `Stable` (click on Options [here](https://gaussian.com/stable/) then see `Opt` which does repeated reoptimizations until the lowest-energy solution is found). Is this something that can be done with DFT+U? The paper you mentioned has 247 citations on GS, anything useful there?

Comment: My consensus from casual conversations with people is that this is an oft-neglected topic. Perhaps it's something that is convenient to "sweep under the rug." Most plane-wave DFT codes, which is where most DFT+U is done, unfortunately do not come with wavefunction stability analyses like in Gaussian, but perhaps an analogous idea could be applied here.

Comment: Anecdotal comment as someone running too much DFT+U, I find that sometimes calculations converge to the same exact magnetic state and identical positions down to some precision, but the only time I have had problems is when the SCF cycles run unstable.  If you have stable convergence behavior, then I don't see this occurring at least qualitatively.

Comment: Anecdotal comment here as well, but I've generally observed the same behavior as you.